# ASP.NET Web API Login History Implementation

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I have searched but have not found any documentation outlining the best way to log each successful or failed attempt to get an access token and store the date/time and IP of the request.  Where would I be able to do this within an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. It's odd that there isn't any interest in answering this question.

After some trial/error and debug tracing, I found that the `ApplicationOAuthProvider`, located in the `Providers` folder in a typical ASP.NET Web API template, contains the following:

```
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        //log the authentication attempt here

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
           OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    }
```

I put a comment in the code to show where logging could be implemented.  I hope that helps.